# Multiple div's onhover same functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I have six different div on hover blue color div should appear and by default hidden. I have written code for this but it works only for the first div I merge all div's in a single variable. Can anyone suggest to me what I'm missing here

```js
var tcpTooltip = $('.tp-cont-tech, tp-cont-b, tp-cont-m, tp-cont-t, tp-cont-i, tp-cont-e');
var tcpTooltipDiv = $('.tpc-tooltip-tech, tpc-tooltip-b, tpc-tooltip-m, tpc-tooltip-t, tpc-tooltip-i, tpc-tooltip-e');
tcpTooltipDiv.hide();
$(tcpTooltip).each(function() {
  $(tcpTooltip).hover(function() {
    $(tcpTooltipDiv).show();
  }, function() {
    $(tcpTooltipDiv).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
/* Tooltip */

.tp-cont-tech,
.tp-cont-e,
.tp-cont-t,
.tp-cont-m,
.tp-cont-i,
.tp-cont-b {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tpc-tooltip-tech,
.tpc-tooltip-e,
.tpc-tooltip-t,
.tpc-tooltip-m,
.tpc-tooltip-i,
.tpc-tooltip-b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tpc-info">
  <div class="tp-cont-tech">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip-tech"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont-b">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip-b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont-m">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip-m"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont-t">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip-t"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont-e">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip-e"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing points in the latter div-selectors: `$('.tp-cont-tech, .tp-cont-b, .tp-cont-m ...)` Extra tip: Add another class like `tp-cont` to all these divs and just select this class.

Comment: @Jb31 Where i have already wrap all div in a single variable.

Comment: `var tcpTooltip = $('.tp-cont-tech, .tp-cont-b, .tp-cont-m, .tp-cont-t, .tp-cont-i, .tp-cont-e')`

Comment: @Shree Thanks i already wrote this code. Can you please make a snippet of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested already, I'd go by using pure CSS and the `:hover` pseudo.
If you really want jQuery for some reason this would be a remake of your code.

Basically (beside adding common classes to your elements [see code below]) you need the `$(this)` reference of the currently hovered element:

```js
var $tpCont = $('.tp-cont');
var $tcpTooltip = $('.tcp-tooltip');

$tcpTooltip.hide();

$tpCont.hover(function() {
  $(this).find($tcpTooltip).toggle();
});
```

```css
.tp-cont {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tcp-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tpc-info">
  <div class="tp-cont tp-cont-tech">
    <div class="tcp-tooltip tpc-tooltip-tech"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont tp-cont-b">
    <div class="tcp-tooltip tpc-tooltip-b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont tp-cont-m">
    <div class="tcp-tooltip tpc-tooltip-m"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont tp-cont-t">
    <div class="tcp-tooltip tpc-tooltip-t"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont tp-cont-e">
    <div class="tcp-tooltip tpc-tooltip-e"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Husna you're welcome. But really, if there's no other complex JS involved while hovering thise elements, think about using pure CSS - if it's all about showing a tooltip on parent `:hover`

Comment: Here relative and absolute div positions are different. In my code relative is parent div and red, blue color both the divs are absolute only thats why `$(this)` is not working Can you see  my codepen link https://codepen.io/Merajkhan/pen/XLBOZj

Comment: In your codepen, the tooltips are not children of `.tcp` but **next** Elements. Use `.next(` instead of `.find(`

Comment: I have added `.next` not working properly to the `<text>` display: none is added and tooltip also not showing.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this far more effectively with CSS. If you add some common classes to the `tp-cont-X` and `tpc-tooltip-X` elements, then you can use the `:hover` pseudo-selector, like this:

```css
.tp-cont {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tpc-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
}

.tp-cont:hover .tpc-tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tpc-info">
  <div class="tp-cont tp-cont-tech">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip tpc-tooltip-tech"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont tp-cont-b">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip tpc-tooltip-b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont tp-cont-m">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip tpc-tooltip-m"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont tp-cont-t">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip tpc-tooltip-t"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont tp-cont-e">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip tpc-tooltip-e"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but here I'm using SVG and all lot of staff are there some times CSS not working properly in SVG   that is why I'm using js To easily understand the code I make it as demo sample code.

Comment: In that case can you please edit the question to include a more accurate example of your code. Although CSS still works with SVG, as you can see in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/fL79mkxd/

Comment: ok I will try but In my code what might is the error. I want to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `index` inside hover.

```js
var tcpTooltip = $('.tp-cont-tech, .tp-cont-b, .tp-cont-m, .tp-cont-t, .tp-cont-i, .tp-cont-e');
var tcpTooltipDiv = $('.tpc-tooltip-tech, .tpc-tooltip-b, .tpc-tooltip-m, .tpc-tooltip-t, .tpc-tooltip-i, .tpc-tooltip-e');
tcpTooltipDiv.hide();
$(tcpTooltip).each(function() {

  $(tcpTooltip).hover(function(index, item) {
    $(tcpTooltipDiv).eq($(this).index()).show();
  }, function() {
    $(tcpTooltipDiv).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
/* Tooltip */

.tp-cont-tech,
.tp-cont-e,
.tp-cont-t,
.tp-cont-m,
.tp-cont-i,
.tp-cont-b {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tpc-tooltip-tech,
.tpc-tooltip-e,
.tpc-tooltip-t,
.tpc-tooltip-m,
.tpc-tooltip-i,
.tpc-tooltip-b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tpc-info">
  <div class="tp-cont-tech">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip-tech"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont-b">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip-b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont-m">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip-m"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont-t">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip-t"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-cont-e">
    <div class="tpc-tooltip-e"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```